# Excel - read 2 values from unknown number of CSV's with different worksheet names into array

Tags: arrays, excel, vbscript

I am another newb to scripting. I've done a lot of searching and haven't been able to find a solution that suits my problem.

- I have a folder with a varying number of CSV's that each contain 1
  worksheet and 2 values in the same cells (A2 & B2).
- The worksheet names are not the same.

Logically I need to create a script that goes to each CSV in this folder, grabs the 2 values and puts them into a single worksheet in an XLS called MonthlyAvg in 2 columns

ie 1st Range goes to A2 & B2 in master document, second A2 & B2 goes into A3 & B3 in master document. My thoughts are that this should be handled in an array. Alas this is where I am stuck as I'm unable to put what I've found on creating arrays logically into what I've put together so far. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
strPath = "D:\MacWP\MacWork\Thermometers\TOT\MonthlyAvg\"      
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objExcel.Visible = True 
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder (strPath) 

 For Each objFile In objFolder.Files      
    If objFso.GetExtensionName (objFile.Path) = "csv" Then 
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
        'Find the first worksheet name
        FirstSheetName = objExcel.Activeworkbook.Worksheets(1).Name         

        'Set the first worksheet name
        Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets (FirstSheetname)

        'Display the value in B2 of the first worksheet     
        MsgBox objSheet.Range("B2").Value
        'Display the value in A2 of the first worksheet
        MsgBox objSheet.Range ("A2").Value          

        objWorkbook.Close False 'Save changes 
    End If      
Next 
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Can you please confirm you want `vbscript` rather than `VBA` run from inside Excel (or other Office apps)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, your file searching is already done, and your only question is how to storage the partial values in a master excel file, right ?

For that, you can use a For cycle with an "index".

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer   
Dim filesOpen As Long

With Application.FileSearch

    .LookIn = "C:\Examples"

    .FileType = msoFileTypeExcelWorkbooks

      'There are wb's

      If .Execute > 0 Then

        For n = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count

          Workbooks.Open (.FoundFiles(i))

        Next n

filesOpen = n

end With

For i = 2 To filesOpen

'i = 2 'fila
j = 1 'columna    

'column A2        
Application.Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("nameOfYourMasterSheet").Cells(i, j).Value = Application.Workbooks("Book1.cvs").Worksheets("nameOfYourSheet").Cells(2, j).Value

'column B2
Application.Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("nameOfYourMasterSheet").Cells(i, j+1).Value = Application.Workbooks("Book1.cvs").Worksheets("nameOfYourSheet").Cells(2, j+1).Value

next i
```

So, the last for cycle is for giving the values to your Master File. The "i" index is the only one which is ascending until you dont have more workbooks.

You don't have to use Arrays, just watch out the "i" value.

Comment: 1) `Application.FileSearch` was deprecated in Office 2007 2) This question appears to ask for `vbscript` - not `vba`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs) as below to write all the values to a `csv` file directly. The code below creats a file `output.csv` under `strPath`

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objFSO
Dim objTF
Dim objWB

strpath = "c:\temp"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strpath)
Set objTF = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strpath & "\output.csv", True, False)
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "csv" Then
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
objTF.WriteLine objWB.Sheets(1).Range("B2") & "," & objWB.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
objWB.Close False 'Save changes
End If
Next

objTF.Close
With objExcel
.DisplayAlerts = True
.Quit
End With
```